# ARIMA with external regressors for district heating load time-series imputation

Tags: r, regression, time-series, arima, data-imputation

TL;DR ARIMA model does not work as expected.

There is a load for district heating with some external regressors like temperature and wind speed. There is missing data which we like to impute. We work with the `fable` framework in `R`.

```
> ts_heat_district
# A tsibble: 70,176 x 7 [15m] <UTC>
   datetime            power_district  temp  wind radiation wm_1w wm_4w
   <dttm>                       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2019-01-01 00:00:00             NA  8     8.18         0  6.71  5.02
 2 2019-01-01 00:15:00             NA  8.02  8.26         0  6.72  5.02
 3 2019-01-01 00:30:00             NA  8.05  8.34         0  6.72  5.02
 4 2019-01-01 00:45:00             NA  8.07  8.43         0  6.73  5.02
 5 2019-01-01 01:00:00             NA  8.1   8.51         0  6.73  5.03
 6 2019-01-01 01:15:00             NA  8.1   8.58         0  6.73  5.03
 7 2019-01-01 01:30:00             NA  8.1   8.66         0  6.74  5.03
 8 2019-01-01 01:45:00             NA  8.1   8.73         0  6.74  5.03
 9 2019-01-01 02:00:00             NA  8.1   8.8          0  6.75  5.04
10 2019-01-01 02:15:00             NA  8.07  8.97         0  6.75  5.04
# ... with 70,166 more rows
```

[image]
[image]

I started with a simple linear regression model which works quite ok. The fourier term should capture the daily pattern. The yearly pattern is captured by temperature and weighted averages from the temperature (variable `wm_1w` and `wm_4w`).

```
fit_heat_district <- ts_heat_district %>%
  model(
    lm = TSLM(power_district ~ temp + I(pmax(15-temp, 0)) + wind + radiation + 
              wm_1w + wm_4w +
              fourier(period = "1 day", K = 24*4/2)),
    arima_fourier = ARIMA(power_district ~ PDQ(0, 0, 0) +
                            temp + I(pmax(15-temp, 0)) + wind + radiation +
                            wm_1w + wm_4w +
                            fourier(period = "1 day", K = 12)),
    arima_seasonal = ARIMA(power_district ~ PDQ(0, 0, 0, period = 24*4) +
                             temp + I(pmax(15-temp, 0)) + wind + radiation +
                             wm_1w + wm_4w)
  )
```

The imputation looks like expected:

```
fit_heat_district %>%
  select("lm") %>%
  fabletools::interpolate(ts_heat_district) %>%
  autoplot() +
  ggtitle("Linear model")
```

[image]

The residuals from external regressors from the linear model seems ok:

```
ts_heat_district %>%
  mutate(temp_15 = ifelse(temp > 15, 0, 15-temp)) %>%
  left_join(residuals(select(fit_heat_district, lm)), by = "datetime") %>%
  pivot_longer(temp:temp_15,
               names_to = "regressor", values_to = "x") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = .resid)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(. ~ regressor, scales = "free_x") +
  labs(y = "Residuals", x = "")
```

[image]

There seems to be some autocorrelation left which should be captured by ARIMA.

```
fit_heat_district %>%
  select(lm) %>%
  gg_tsresiduals()
```

[image]

I tried a seasonal ARIMA model and a non-seasonal ARIMA model with a Fourier term because the period is relatively long (24*4=96).

```
fit_heat_district <- ts_heat_district %>%
  model(
    lm = TSLM(power_district ~ temp + I(pmax(15-temp, 0)) + wind + radiation + 
              wm_1w + wm_4w +
              fourier(period = "1 day", K = 24*4/2)),
    arima_fourier = ARIMA(power_district ~ PDQ(0, 0, 0) +
                            temp + I(pmax(15-temp, 0)) + wind + radiation +
                            wm_1w + wm_4w +
                            fourier(period = "1 day", K = 12)),
    arima_seasonal = ARIMA(power_district ~ PDQ(0, 0, 0, period = 24*4) +
                             temp + I(pmax(15-temp, 0)) + wind + radiation +
                             wm_1w + wm_4w)
  )
```

The interpolated data from the ARIMA models don't look as expected:

```
fit_heat_district %>%
  select("arima_fourier") %>%
  fabletools::interpolate(ts_heat_district) %>%
  autoplot() +
  ggtitle("arima model with fourier")
```

[image]

```
fit_heat_district %>%
  select("arima_seasonal") %>%
  fabletools::interpolate(ts_heat_district) %>%
  autoplot() +
  ggtitle("seasonal arima model")
```

[image]

What is wrong with the ARIMA models? What am I missing?

**EDIT 2021-04-07**

Some additional information:

- tried versions with box-cox transformation to stabilize variance (got lambda via Guerrero's method); at least both AIC and MAE for linear model improved slightly
- KPSS test: one time differencing is necessary
- for seasonal differencing p-value would be 0.0723
- tried solutions from similiar posts on CV like setting D = 1 and period = 96
- tried models without external regressors (keep it simple):

*ARIMA w/ fourier*

`ARIMA(box_cox(heat_output, lambda = lambda) ~ pdq(0:5, 1, 0:5) + PDQ(0, 0, 0) + fourier(period = "1 day", K = 12))`

`<LM w/ ARIMA(5,1,0) errors>`

Forecast and imputation values are still a straight line.

*ARIMA w/o fourier*

`ARIMA(box_cox(heat_output, lambda = lambda) ~ pdq(0:5, 1, 0:5) + PDQ(0:2, 1, 0:2, period = 96))`

`<ARIMA(5,1,0)(0,1,0)[96]>`

Interpolation looks strange and model is very slow:

[image]

I am wondering wether ARIMA is just not an appropriate method for this kind of time series.

Any information is very welcome.